# Get text for EventCategory rather than just integer

Tags: python, windows, winapi

The below code requires the win32 extensions. Anyways, I have been going through the Orielly Book "Python Programming On Win32" and am interested in being able to read events.

However, right now reading an event category will return an integer.

How would one lookup the actual *name* of the category?
What I've got so far is this

```
import win32evtlog

hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(None, "Application")
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ | win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
event = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(hand, flags, 0)[0]
event.EventCategory
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to interpret on your own.
Write an enum or case statement and print text accordingly.

Hex value: (decimal value in brackets)

```
EVENTLOG_SUCCESS                0x0000 (decimal - 0)
EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE             0x0001 (decimal - 1)
EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE           0x0002 (decimal - 2)
EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE       0x0004 (decimal - 4)
EVENTLOG_AUDIT_SUCCESS          0x0008 (decimal - 8)
EVENTLOG_AUDIT_FAILURE          0x0010 (decimal - 16)
```